# Flannel interface don't create on kubernetes worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, cni

I have multiple kvm nodes from different network. All these nodes has two iface `eth0: 10.0.2.15/24`, `eth1: 10.201.(14|12|11).0/24` and few manual routes between dc.

```
root@k8s-hv09:~# ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 
10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100 
10.201.12.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.201.12.179 
10.201.14.0/24 via 10.201.12.2 dev eth1 proto static 
10.201.11.0/24 via 10.201.12.2 dev eth1 proto static
```

Description for all nodes

```
Ubuntu 16.04/18.04
Kubernetes 1.13.2
Kubernetes-cni 0.6.0
docker-ce 18.06.1
```

Master node(k8s-hv06)

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controlPlaneEndpoint: 10.201.14.176:6443
controllerManager: {}
dns:
  type: CoreDNS
etcd:
  external:
    caFile: ""
    certFile: ""
    endpoints:
    - http://10.201.14.176:2379
    - http://10.201.12.180:2379
    - http://10.201.11.171:2379
    keyFile: ""
imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.13.2
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: {}
```

Flannel v0.10.0 was used with rbac and additional arg --iface=eth1.
One or more master nodes working fine.

```
root@k8s-hv06:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-b4tf9                    1/1     Running   2          23h
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-h6nq8                    1/1     Running   2          23h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-hv06                     1/1     Running   3          23h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-hv06            1/1     Running   5          23h
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-rsmhj                 1/1     Running   0          21h
kube-system   kube-proxy-s5n8l                            1/1     Running   3          23h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-hv06                     1/1     Running   4          23h
```

But I cant add any worker node to cluster. For example, I have clear installation Ubuntu 18.04 with docker-ce, kubeadm, kubelet

```
root@k8s-hv09:~# dpkg -l | grep -E 'kube|docker' | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
hi docker-ce      18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
hi kubeadm        1.13.2-00
hi kubectl        1.13.2-00
hi kubelet        1.13.2-00
ii kubernetes-cni 0.6.0-00
```

and I'm trying to add worker node(k8s-hv09) to cluster

```
root@k8s-hv06:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
k8s-hv06      Ready    master   23h   v1.13.2
k8s-hv09      Ready    <none>   31s   v1.13.2

root@k8s-hv06:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-b4tf9                    1/1     Running            2          23h
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-h6nq8                    1/1     Running            2          23h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-hv06                     1/1     Running            3          23h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-hv06            1/1     Running            5          23h
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-cqw5p                 0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          113s
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-rsmhj                 1/1     Running            0          22h
kube-system   kube-proxy-hbnpq                            1/1     Running            0          113s
kube-system   kube-proxy-s5n8l                            1/1     Running            3          23h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-hv06                     1/1     Running            4          23h
```

`cni0` and `flannel.1` didn't create and connection to master node can't be established.

```
root@k8s-hv09:~# ip a | grep -E '(flannel|cni|cbr|eth|docker)'
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:fa:99:0d:3b:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:da:44:d9:2e:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.201.12.179/24 brd 10.201.12.255 scope global eth1
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:30:71:67:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.172.172.2/24 brd 172.172.172.255 scope global docker0
```

```
root@k8s-hv06:~# kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-amd64-cqw5p -n kube-system -c kube-flannel
I0129 13:02:09.244309       1 main.go:488] Using interface with name eth1 and address 10.201.12.179
I0129 13:02:09.244498       1 main.go:505] Defaulting external address to interface address (10.201.12.179)
E0129 13:02:09.246907       1 main.go:232] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-cqw5p': Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-cqw5p: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

```
root@k8s-hv09:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
64a9b21607cb        quay.io/coreos/flannel   "cp -f /etc/kube-fla…"   23 minutes ago       Exited (0) 23 minutes ago                           k8s_install-cni_kube-flannel-ds-amd64-4k2dt_kube-system_b8f510e3-23c7-11e9-85a5-1a05eef25a13_0
2e0145137449        f0fad859c909             "/opt/bin/flanneld -…"   About a minute ago   Exited (1) About a minute ago                       k8s_kube-flannel_kube-flannel-ds-amd64-4k2dt_kube-system_b8f510e3-23c7-11e9-85a5-1a05eef25a13_9
90271ee02f68        k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy    "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   23 minutes ago       Up 23 minutes                                       k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-6zgjq_kube-system_b8f50ef6-23c7-11e9-85a5-1a05eef25a13_0
b6345e9d8087        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1     "/pause"                 23 minutes ago       Up 23 minutes                                       k8s_POD_kube-proxy-6zgjq_kube-system_b8f50ef6-23c7-11e9-85a5-1a05eef25a13_0
dca408f8a807        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1     "/pause"                 23 minutes ago       Up 23 minutes                                       k8s_POD_kube-flannel-ds-amd64-4k2dt_kube-system_b8f510e3-23c7-11e9-85a5-1a05eef25a13_0
```

I see command `/opt/bin/flanneld --iface=eth1 --ip-masq --kube-subnet-mgr` running on the worker node but terminate after container k8s_install-cni_kube-flannel-ds-amd64 stopped. File `/etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist` and directory `/opt/cni/bin` is presents.

I dont understand the reason. If I add new master node to cluster it will work fine.

```
root@k8s-hv06:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
k8s-hv01      Ready    master   17s     v1.13.2
k8s-hv06      Ready    master   22m     v1.13.2
k8s-hv09      Ready    <none>   6m22s   v1.13.2

root@k8s-hv06:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-b8th2                    1/1     Running            0          23m
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-hmm8q                    1/1     Running            0          23m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-hv01                     1/1     Running            0          2m16s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-hv06                     1/1     Running            0          23m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-hv01            1/1     Running            0          2m16s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-hv06            1/1     Running            0          23m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-92kmc                 0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          8m20s
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-krdgt                 1/1     Running            0          2m16s
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-lpgkt                 1/1     Running            0          10m
kube-system   kube-proxy-7ck7f                            1/1     Running            0          23m
kube-system   kube-proxy-nbkvg                            1/1     Running            0          8m20s
kube-system   kube-proxy-nvbcw                            1/1     Running            0          2m16s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-hv01                     1/1     Running            0          2m16s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-hv06                     1/1     Running            0          23m
```

But not worker node.

Update:

I don't have issue connection to api server. My issue is two ifaces(`cni`, `flannel`). Without these ifaces I don't have sync between master and worker nodes.
Ok let take once additional node and add it to cluster. If i use `kubeadm-init` with my config file all will work fine. Ifaces of flannel plugin is presents. Let make `kubeadm reset`** and `kubeadm join` this node to same cluster. Network interfaces is absent. But why? In the both case we have the same way to get data for network configuration from master api.
If I had found any errors or warning I would have a clue.

```
** kubectl delete node <node name>(on master)
kubeadm reset && docker system prune -a && reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. API server was bind to eth0 instead of eth1. This is my mistake. I'm very embarrassed.

Additional master node work fine because it healthcheck his own apiserver iface. But this don't work for worker node.

/Close

Answer (score 0):

There is similar [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/193) to your case and it has been solved by manually editing `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` on the master and changing the liveness probe:

```
livenessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 8
  httpGet:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    path: /healthz
    port: 443           # was 6443
    scheme: HTTPS
```

I hope it would help